# OneSignal not working with amazon devices in my ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I'm working on a ionic app project, in which I'm using **OneSignal** for push notification, everything is fine when I'm testing the app with Google Android devices, but when testing over Amazon devices then not getting notification. When I check **OneSignal** dashboard it shows ***No Push Token*** for amazon devices.

[image: Screenshot from OneSignal Dashboard]

Comment: onesignal probably requires google play services. Are you sure they are available on amazon devices?

Comment: Not sure if amazon devices have google play services or not.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same problem